# MSVC throws error when bitfield is bigger than underlying type. Is that standard conform?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

The C++20 standard (N4892) states:

> If the width of a bit-field
> is larger than the width of the bit-field’s type (or, in case of an enumeration type, of its underlying type),
> the extra bits are padding bits (6.8).

in 11.4.10.1.

This seems to indicate that bit fields with more bits than the underlying type are allowed. However, when I try to compile the following code with MSVC, an error is thrown:

```
#include <cstdint>

struct S
{
    int32_t i : 33;
};
```

[C2034](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2034?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(C2034)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-160): type of bit field too small for number of bits

Is this behavior allowed by the standard?

Comment: Pretty sure this is an error in the standard, and it’s supposed to read ‘smaller’.

Comment: [C++11 (or the closest thing I can link to) words it a bit differently, but seems to say the same thing.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.bit#1) Either way, that's a good warning. What are you going to do with more bits than you can hold? Shouldn't be a hard error, though.

Comment: @user4581301 I do not really have a use case for this, it's just morbid language curiosity. It's not a warning by the way, but an error.

Comment: According to cppreference: "If the specified size of the bit field is greater than the size of its type, the value is limited by the type: a std::uint8_t b : 1000; would still hold values between 0 and 255. the extra bits become unused padding." So it should be ok to create a bitfield larger than the type but you can't access any of those extra bits.

Comment: gcc 10.2 only gives a warning: https://godbolt.org/z/7zsncPYTE

Comment: @Brotcrunsher Yeah, I fired up VS2015, checked, and then amended. I can see why MS might want that as an error, even if it's non-Standard. Only use case I can think of would be you plan to extend the bitfield in the future and don't want the object to change size.